# Android Studio Gradle 3.0 error when compiling java project

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

before updating to AS and Gradle 3.0, I had created a separate java module in my android project to run tests. It had its own build.gradle and run configurations. It used to work perfectly until I upgraded to gradle 3. Now, when I try to compile it gives me the following error :

```
 Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'RUN'.
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
     http://dl.bintray.com/sergiocasero/maven/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
     http://dl.bintray.com/sergiocasero/maven/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar
 Required by:
     project :
```

The build.gradle file for the module is the following :

```
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

This file was created using the AS wizard.

I do not understand why gradle is looking for the android build tools when building a java project. Anyone have any idea how I can get my module to compile? Thanks.

Comment: Does the project have an Android module (app or library) along with this Java module? If so, your problem is in your project-level `build.gradle` file -- you need to add `google()` to both `repositories` closures. If not, your project-level `build.gradle` file has a reference to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` which you do not need (if you're not building Android modules in this project) and could remove.

Comment: @CommonsWare That was it thank you! If you want you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it to close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project has 1+ Android modules, the `classpath` request to load the Android Plugin for Gradle will be in the project-level `build.gradle` file, and the contents of that file is used even for non-Android modules.

If you add `google()` to both `repositories` closure, you will be able to load this plugin. As a side benefit, you will also be able to start using the newer versions of the various Google libraries in your Android modules (e.g., `com.android.support` artifacts), which also come from Google's Maven repo.